# How do I ensure that two random integers listed in the same range but for different variables will not be the same?

Tags: python

My assignment has me modifying a Dragon Realm text adventure game to have four different caves to go in. How do I make sure the player does not enter two caves simultaneously?

I have tried several different functions, including 'if', 'while', and several functions from the random library, and while I sometimes look like I'm getting somewhere, subsequent retries at the game will see the code for one cave tangled with another that was chosen; for instance, cave1's text will show, followed by cave2's text as if the player had chosen cave2.

```
cave1 = random.randint(1, 4)
cave2 = random.randint(1, 4)
cave3 = random.randint(1, 4)

if chosenCave == str(cave1):
        print('Gives you his treasure!')
if chosenCave == str(cave2):
        print('Does nothing, just exhales. He barely pays you any mind.')
        time.sleep(2)
        print('''You see he has no treasure. You decide it's not worth
        the risk to be eaten for treasure, and head home sadly.''')
if chosenCave == str(cave3):
        print('''Says, "I have no treasure. I was in the middle of a
        nice nap. Just get out of here.''')
        time.sleep(2)
        print('''You say, "Sorry...?" and leave the cave for home, confused.''')
else:
     print('Gobbles you down in one bite!')
```

All I want is to make sure the player enters only one cave with no text from the others showing. It's incorrect to see "'Gives you his treasure!'" followed immediately by "'Gobbles you down in one bite!'" I expect to see just one cave's text while the others stay put instead of being tangled with one another, making sure that this is not repeated on further attempts.

Comment: Change all `if`s after first `if` to `elif` a.k.a else if.

Comment: With your code, `'Gobbles you down in one bite!'` is printed for all cases where `chosenCave` does not equal `str(cave3)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `sample` function from the `random` module.

```
>>> cave1, cave2, cave3 = random.sample(range(1, 5), 3)
```

Also, alter your code such that each `if` statement following the first one is an `elif`, otherwise your `else` for that final `if` statement will run most of the time (whenever `chosenCave != str(cave3)`).

Answer (score 0):

With the help of `set`s you can do what you want, for example:

```
>>> import random
>>> choices = set()
while len(choices) < 3:
    choices.add(random.randint(1,4))

>>> cave1, cave2, cave3 = choices
>>> cave1, cave2, cave3
(2, 3, 4)
>>>
```

Hope it helps.